# Setting environment variable in python has no effect on cfgrib

Tags: python, python-xarray, cfgrib, eccodes

I am using xarray with cfgrib to load grib files in Python. I have custom grib definitions, which I am providing to eccodes (backend for cfgrib) via the environment variable `GRIB_DEFINITION_PATH`.
This setup works well, as long as I run the Python script in an environment where the variable was already set.

Now I want to be more flexible with my setup and provide the environment variable from within Python using `os.environ` (see the example below).
But somehow when setting up the environment like this, the variable gets ignored and I don't understand why.
Can anyone provide me some insight into this mystery? Thanks in advance!

Here an "MRE" of the setting.

```
import xarray as xr
import os

grib_definitions_path = "/paths/to/definitions:/split/like/this"
os.environ["GRIB_DEFINITION_PATH"] = grib_definitions_path

grib_file = '/path/to/grib/file'
backend_args = {
    "filter_by_keys": {"shortName": "P"}
}
array = xr.open_dataset(grib_file, engine="cfgrib", encode_cf=("geography", "vertical"), backend_kwargs=backend_args)["P"]
print(array.dims)
```

Executing the above code in a terminal fails for me with `KeyError: 'P'`. If I however first run

```
export GRIB_DEFINITION_PATH="/paths/to/definitions:/split/like/this"
```

the dimensions of `array` are being printed as expected.

Comment: Try setting the environment before you `import xarray`

Comment: How in the world?... I already tried that but it didn't work earlier. But now it somehow seems to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You still need to run that line after `os.environ["GRIB_DEFINITION_PATH"] = grib_definitions_path`
Add the following
`subprocess.check_call(['sqsub', '-np', sys.argv[1], grib_definitions_path ],env=dict(os.environ, SQSUB_VAR="visible in this subprocess"))`

Comment: @blackbird Can you explain why? I don't have `sqsub` and I also don't pass any arguments to my run script, hence `sys.argv[1]` would be undefined.